# recursive exercise on codingbat

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am currently working on an exercise on `codingbat` website which says:

> Given an array of ints, compute recursively if the array contains a 6.
>   We'll use the convention of considering only the part of the array
>   that begins at the given index. In this way, a recursive call can pass
>   index+1 to move down the array. The initial call will pass in index as
>   0.

**Example:**

***array6([1, 6, 4], 0) → true***

***array6([1, 4], 0) → false***

***array6([6], 0) → true***

my solution is below but for some reason when my `if(nums[index] == 6)` is true it still executes the code within the `else block.`

**My Question:**

Technically, it should not execute the code within the `else block` when the code within the `if statement` is executed. so why does that persist?;

```
public static boolean array6(int[] nums, int index) { 

    if(nums.length == 0){
          return false;
    }

    if(index == nums.length-1 && nums[index] != 6){
          return false;
    }

    if(index == nums.length-1 && nums[index] == 6){
          return true;
    }

    if(nums[index] == 6){
           return true;

    }else{
           array6(nums,index+1);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return the value you receive by recursion. Change

```
array6(nums,index+1);
```

to something like

```
return array6(nums,index+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean find(int[] a, int value) {
    if (a == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument!");
    }
    return find(a, value, 0);
}

private static boolean find(int[] a, int value, int index) {
    if (index == a.length) return false;
    if (a[index] == value) return true;
    return find(a, value, index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if my answer satisfies your question

```
public boolean array6(int[] nums, int index) {
  if(nums.length == 0 || index > nums.length-1){
    return false;
  }
  if(nums[index] == 6){
    return true;
  }

  return array6(nums,index+1);
}
```